# haxe/OpenFL: How to destroy/remove a brick

Tags: html, flash, collision-detection, haxe, openfl

I think this is rather strange that I haven't found anything... which means the answer is really simple but I'm not getting it or it's something else.

I'm using haxe and openFL and the exercise is specific about not using any other frameworks. I'm building an Atari breakout clone. I'm trying to handle the collision event between the block and the ball. All the blocks are stored in an array `map[]` which is being iterated.

```
if ( (ball.x > (map[i].x) && ball.x < (map[i].x+20)) && (ball.y > (map[i].y) && ball.y < (map[i].y+20)) ) {
                    this.removeChild(map[i]);
                    ballMovement.y *= -1;
                }
```

The ball has 10px radius and each block is 20x20. (Also, yes the ball will bounce awkwardly but I haven't had time to make a decent bouncing function yet, so that'll have to do for now)

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour. Yes the blocks disappear now, but Sometimes it seems the ball bounces off invisible blocks. The question is, am I removing those elements properly? Is the collision detection not properly set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should remove your block(map[i]) from **map** also, because seems that you check collision with map elements, not display elements.

Comment: of course, I wasn't removing it from the array. I noticed it right the next morning. One of the problems of staying up late coding :P thanks very much.